# Array/pointer addition

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand the following code

```
uchar  abyHeader[100];
i32 = psSHP->nFileSize / 2;    
ByteCopy(&i32, abyHeader + 24, 4);
```

where

```
#define ByteCopy( a, b, c ) memcpy( b, a, c )
```

I understand how memcpy works. However, I am not sure what `abyHeader + 24` does to abyHeader. I know that if we have a `uchar*`, this would skip 24 elements and point to the next element. Does the array work the same?

Comment: Since you're in C++ you should steer far, far away from using `#define`. That definition you have there isn't sufficiently robust as the values could be non-trivial. Instead use a function wrapper, even an `inline` one. If this is code you've been given it's really sloppy and pretty much pointless since it just shuffles the arguments and obscures what's actually happening, impairing understanding.

Comment: In general terms `*(x + n)` and `x[n]` produce the same result, so `x + 24` is akin to `&x[24]` or in other words, adding `24 * sizeof(uchar)` to the pointer.

Comment: Thanks! This code is given to me and I am just trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: Yes, arrays (`abyHeader`) *decay* to pointers in many situations. `abyHeader + 24` is the same as `&abyHeader[24]`, so yes, it works the same as with a `uchar*`.

Comment: Any C or C++ worth anything knows what `memcpy` does.  There is no need for a `#define` macro there.  It's equivalent to replacing a steering wheel for a car with a joystick.

Comment: ...LOL yes, and that car is shared by all future maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abyHeader + 24` does nothing to `abyHeader`. That expression in the parameter passes it result as an argument. Does the array work the same because array is actually a pointer to your first position.

Comment: The result is stored as argument, in second parameter. As ````secondParameter = abyHeader + 24````.